# Does python dictionary capacity increase dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, hashmap, cpython

Let's say in python3, we used a dictionary as:

```
my_dct = {}
...
for i in range(100):
  my_dct[i] = True
...
for s in "potentially long string":
  my_dct[s] = True
```

My question is when we run the above python program through the python interpreter, what capacity container does the interpreter create at the first line? Depending on this size, does the capacity increase during the course of the *first or second for loop*?

[This link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html) shows capacity 8. While [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c) shows, according to the type, 128, 2^15, etc. as the capacity of the container upon the instantiation of a dictionary in python.

Would really appreciate any explanation, thank you.

Comment: The first link is 10 years old.  Why do you need to know?

Comment: Because I want to have an exact understanding in this case. I am wondering about the pros and cons of using list vs dictionary to solve leetcode-like problems. Since a list is a container and I knew dictionary uses container internally ... hope it made sense to you

Comment: "what capacity container does the interpreter create at the first line?" what do you mean by *capacity*. In general, container types don't have "capacities" (and if they do, they are internal implementation details). Containers have a *length*, and depending on whether they are mutable or immutable, they can change that length

Comment: A dictionary *is a container* precisely in the same sense that a *list is a container*. Both, underneath the hood, use more primitive data structures implemented in C that you could call "containers" as well, speaking generically.

Comment: " I am wondering about the pros and cons of using list vs dictionary to solve leetcode-like problems." The pros and cons are the standard pros and cons of working with an array-list vs a hashmap. Although note, in this case, Python's dict implements a clever, ordered hash map that you can read the details about in the first link and the actual source code in the second link

Comment: "While this shows, according to the type, 128, 2^15, etc. as the capacity of the container upon the instantiation of a dictionary in python." Where does this show that? I don't see that anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the `dict` storage adjusts as it grows is an implementation detail, which most users don't need to know.  If you are developer, or want to write your own code in C, the details may be useful.  But for choosing between lists and dicts, they don't matter.

The important difference between lists and dicts is how they are indexed.  A list is indexed by integers (or slices), and 'contains' all values up to its `len`.  A dict is indexed by keys, which can be any hashable object.  Strings are most common.

```
In [1]: import sys
```

On the surface these two objects are equivalent:

```
In [2]: adict = {i:True for i in range(100)}
In [3]: alist = [i for i in range(100)]
```

Both have `len()` 100, and can be indexed the same way:

```
In [4]: adict[50]
Out[4]: True
In [5]: alist[50]
Out[5]: 50
```

Oops, I meant to use `alist = [True for i in range(100)]`, a list of 100 `True` values, rather than `list(range(100))`.  But that doesn't change the following discussion.

A key difference is that the list indices have to be consecutive.  That is if we want to use `alist[200]`, we will have to add another 101 values to the list.  Whereas `adict[200]=False` simply adds the `200` to the hash table, with a new `len` of 101.

Underlying storage is quite different.

`alist` has a C array that contains references for 100 values, plus some 'head room' to allow for fast growth with `alist.append(...)`.

`adict` has a hash table, that somehow stores references to the keys and the values.

In both cases, as they grow, the storage ('container'?) will have to be reallocated when it fills up.  Again the details are implementation dependent, and largely invisible to users - unless we carefully track memory or times.

I've seen a number of SO questions that try to compare the `getsizeof` of list and arrays.  The answers always point out that this comparison has limited value, since it measures very different things.

```
In [8]: sys.getsizeof(alist)
Out[8]: 904
In [9]: sys.getsizeof(adict)
Out[9]: 4696
```

For a `list`, `getsizeof` is basically the size of the C array that stores value references.  For `len(alist)` of 100, that's 8*100 bytes, with roughly growth space for 13 more values - at which point it will have to be reallocated.

Adding 6 values does not change size:

```
In [11]: alist.extend([True]*6)
In [12]: len(alist)
Out[12]: 106
In [13]: sys.getsizeof(alist)
Out[13]: 904
```

Adding another 6, forces a reallocation, with a larger head space (for 27 references):

```
In [14]: alist.extend([True]*6)
In [15]: len(alist)
Out[15]: 112
In [16]: sys.getsizeof(alist)
Out[16]: 1112
```

I assume the `getsizeof(adict)` measures the size of the hashtable.  That's quite a bit larger.

Adding 12 more keys to `adict` doesn't change the size.  There's enough space to handle these values without clashes.

```
In [21]: adict.update({i:True for i in range(100,106)})
In [22]: len(adict)
Out[22]: 106
In [23]: sys.getsizeof(adict)
Out[23]: 4696
In [24]: adict.update({i:True for i in range(106,112)})
In [25]: sys.getsizeof(adict)
Out[25]: 4696
```

For total memory foot print we also have to consider the memory use of the keys and values.  In these examples, that isn't much, since all references to `True` reference the same object.  And ints up to 255 are also preallocated and unique.  But keys can be strings, tuples, or more complex objects.  And values can be an object, though adding them to a list or dict does increase memory use.  They are stored by reference, not value.